# Дух сообщества - не робот

Tags: обсуждение, дух-сообщества

На enSO у духа сообщества обнаружился знак "не робот". Это такой троллинг с первого апреля убрать забыли или так задумано? Судя по дате, с 1 апреля не связано. У нашего, кстати, такого нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Робот не может причинить вред человеку. А этот - может. Юзеров банит, вопросы закрывает...

Comment: Скорее всего знак дали боту по приколу, не более того :p

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это шикарно)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov классно подмечено!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Когда-то я заметил этот бейджик у комюнити юзера и это меня рассмешило)

Возможно, это отсылка к [капче](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0) (тест на то что ты не бот), а именно к [мемам про то, капча пропускает робота](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsF7enQY8uI).

Во всяком случае, этот бейджик был выдан роботу [в качестве пасхалки](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot), см. ответ Ника.